# Roundup all computations in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a code in VBA with many floating point calculations. The end result is not accurate and is underestimated. While accuracy may be tough to achieve I would like to at least overestimate all the calculation results as I am working on a civil beam design problem and overestimating is safer. I would like to know if there is any way to round up all calculations in VBA by default for this particular code.
Something like c++ ios base or changing Mathematica's environment (I do not recall the exact terminology).

Comment: are you talking about rounding up `double` data type?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do with your code when you say rounding up? Please clarify with a few examples. For all the shortcomings of VBA, by its nature of being a non-compiled language, its floating point calculations are faithfully accurate to the degree of precision of its variables IMHO

Comment: Are you implementing some sort of finite difference method? Because, in that case, you'll need to be sure the scheme you have employed in unconditionally stable or at least stable within the bounds of your problem

Answer (score 0):

You would use the same approach you would use in worksheet formulas:

```
Sub RoundTest()
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, approximate As Double, tVale As Double
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    tVale = wf.Pi()
    approximate = wf.RoundUp(tVale, 3#)
    MsgBox tVale & vbCrLf & approximate
End Sub
```